# Swiftui .alert modifier's button won't set @State presentation var back to false

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

What's wrong in code below that prevents ***showingAlert*** variable to be reset back to false on alert dismiss?

I'm probably missing some point that has something to deal with the ***onreceive*** modifier...

Here's the sample code.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false

    @State private var myValue: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(showingAlert ? "T" : "F")
            TextField("placeholder",  text: $myValue)
            .onReceive(Just(myValue)) { newValue in
                self.showingAlert = true
            }
        }

        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("SOME VALUE..."), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
        }
    }
}
```

BTW it won't work neither if you try to *force* this way:

```
...

 .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("SOME VALUE..."), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")) {
                    self.showingAlert = false
                })
        }

...
```

Thanks in advance and blessed Easter everybody ...

GpE

Answer (score 1):

Your `alert` is working as expected and is resetting the value of `showingAlert`

The problem with `onReceive`. It adds an action to perform when this view detects data emitted by the given publisher and changes `showingAlert` to true right when the dialog is closed.

```
TextField("placeholder",  text: $myValue, onEditingChanged: {
        if !$0 {
            print($0)
            self.showingAlert = true
        }
    })
```

With the above code, the user will receive an alert every time they click close the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks @sfung3 . Your answer confirms that I have to dig deeper into _onreceive_ modifier. Unfortunately I'd like to present the alert during text input validation while typing, hence the use of this particular modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround (think that something cleaner is surely possible... but it works for the moment!)

Also slightly modified the code for a clearer view of why I'm using ***onreceive***.

In the example I want the alert showed if the third letter typed is a 'Z' (uppercased...). ***iAlertCheck*** var makes the trick: it is set to a constant value right before the alert is dismissed. Than it's tested inside the *onreceive* and if == constant than both vars (***iAlertCheck*** and ***showingAlert***) are reset.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

extension String {
    subscript(i: Int) -> String {
        return String(self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)])
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false

    @State private var myValue: String = ""

    static var iCount: Int = 0
    static var iAlertCheck = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(showingAlert ? "T" : "F")
            TextField("placeholder",  text: $myValue)
            .onReceive(Just(myValue)) { newValue in


                ContentView.iCount += 1
                print("\(ContentView.iCount): iAlertCheck: \(ContentView.iAlertCheck)")

                if newValue.count == 3 && newValue[2] == "Z" {
                    if ContentView.iAlertCheck == 0 {
                        self.showingAlert = true
                    }
                    else if ContentView.iAlertCheck == -10 {
                        ContentView.iAlertCheck = 0
                        self.showingAlert = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("SOME VALUE..."), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")) {
                ContentView.iAlertCheck = -10
            })
        }
    }
}
```